# Is there a way to set the selected value in JQM select?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following code to update my jquerymobile enhanced HTML select tag:

```
  var selectTuner = $("#tunerselector");
  selectTuner[0].selectedIndex = 4;
  selectTuner.selectmenu(); // Needed this o/w initialisation error on refresh.
  selectTuner.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Is there a way of setting the value instead o selectedIndex?

The problem I have is I have two ajax requests, one to get the option values for the select tag (from an xml file) and one to get the selected value (from a database table). I do not want to chain my ajax requests so I would like to know if I can set the value rather than the index of the select tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$("#tunerselector option[value='yourValueAtIndex4']").attr('selected', 'selected');  
$('#tunerselector').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. Resets the select option to the first in the list.

Comment: Maybe you can try the following: `$("#tunerselector option[value='yourValueAtIndex4']").attr('selected', 'selected'); $('#tunerselector').selectmenu('refresh');`